# How do I secure an API key correctly?

Tags: php, android, slim

I'm currently working on an API that is going to be used in an app and a website. For some actions, you have to be logged in and for others not. Users are also split up into different account types like e.g. users and support.
For the API I've used the slim framework.

So my approach is the following:

> - The API key with its type is stored in the database and its bond to an account
> - I assign group permissions to each command, which restricts e.g. not logged in users

The following is an example of a request:

> https://myapiwebsite.com/index.php/api/v1/getSupportTickets?apikey=Test

In this example, not logged in users and normal users are restricted, but support users not.
As this is already working, I have to ask myself if this is even secure, because someone could e.g. spoof the support users' API key and disguises himself as support staff.
How can I secure my API, or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider placing the support functionality into a different website URL that is served by a different `<VirtualHost>` *(Apache ...)* and then use `mod_ssl` to secure it using a public key that is shared with only the support staff.

"Yes, `mod_ssl` cuts both ways."  It *can* be used to secure a web-site to require the user to have a corresponding public key which can be revoked.  See `Require ssl-verify-client`.

You can also use other applications of crypto technology such as [Open]VPNs, which can even be used to *conceal* the secret doorways that lead inside.  (See `tls-auth` in OpenVPN.)

This basically makes it *impossible* for unauthorized people to gain access to the sensitive functionality, whether or not they (also ...) possess an API key.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the API key to your query parameters, there is a high risk that all your "secret" API keys will be logged in some web server or proxy log files. Later you can neither tell where these keys are stored nor do you have the possibility to delete them.

Better submit the API-Key in a HTTP header like [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization), e.g.

`Authorization: Bearer cn389ncoiwuencr`

Also make sure that the traffic is always encrypted using SSL.